# NoMethodError User Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I'm trying out user authentication for the first time and am running to a bit of an issue.

I've defined my `make_salt` method in my AdminUser model

```
def self.make_salt(username="")
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Use #{username} and other stuff")
end
```

Then in my console when I run `AdminUser.make_salt`, I get:

```
>> AdminUser.make_salt
NoMethodError: undefined method `make_salt' for #<Class:0x1063ddb58>
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/base.rb:1009:in `method_missing'
from (irb):30
```

Also, I had a `hash` method defined, which worked fine, but when I changed it to `hash_with_salt` I also got a NoMethodError.

Am I just missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. Finally figured out this one. I simply needed to restart my console after saving the changes to my code.

Comment: In the console you can also call a method `reload!` - this usually is enough. Of course, restarting is more reliable.